Как поставить новый шрифт в VSСode в Linux?
Я скачал шрифты от JetBrains и положили их в ~/.fonts Далее в VSCode в настройках в Editor font 'JetBrains Mono'. Но после перезапуска у меня ни чего не сработало

Для начала проверить что эти шрифты вообще нашлись. fc-list | grep JetBrains, например

@Список пуст( Что можно сделать ? Я вроде обнавил шрифты.

Попробовать переложить в ~/.local/share/fonts. Папка ~/.fonts считается устаревшей. Ну и запустить fc-cache -r на всякий случай

Какой дистрибутив хоть? С 95% вероятностью этот шрифт уже есть в репозиториях

Откройте файл шрифта в приложении просмотра шривтов и нажмите кнопку установить:

Должно заработать.

нет такой программы(

@AslanPAPA что происходит если вы два раза нажимате по файлу .ttf в файловом менеджере?

Ошибка Unknow file type т.е нет прогарммы для открытия этого файла нажимаю открыть с помощью и там разные программы, но просмотр шрифта нет

@AslanPAPA значит установите такую.

Спасибо установил программу далее в ней установил шрифт и все получилось!
